# Given $(f_n)$ in $L^{p}(E)$, with $\|f_{n}\|_{p} \leq 1$ and $f_{n} \to f$ almost everywhere. Show $f \in L^{p}(E) $ and $\|f\|_{p} \leq1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am currently stuck on proving part of this measure theory question:

> Given a sequence $(f_n)$ in $L^{p}(E)$ $(1 \leq p < \infty)$, with $\|f_{n}\|_{p} \leq 1$ and $f_{n} \to f$ almost everywhere. Show $f \in L^{p}(E) $ and $\|f\|_{p} \leq1.$

For showing that $\|f\|_{p} \leq 1$ I have the following:

By using Fatou's lemma, we have that $$\begin{align}
\|f\|_p &= \left(\int_{E} |f|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_{E} |f_n|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p\\
&\leqslant 1.
\end{align}$$

I feel like this is correct, but I also think this could be shown by showing that $f \in L^{p}(E)$ which is what I am stuck on. I understand that $\|f_{n} -f\|_{p} \to 0 \iff \|f_{n}\|_{p} \to \|f\|_{p}$, but that would imply that $f \in L^{p}(E)$ in the first place - hence I am unsure of how to proceed. Any hints, feedback or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In fatou's lemma, neither side needs to be finite, so this actually proves $f \in L^p$

Comment: your solution is right, note that if $f_n\to f$ pointwise then it can be shown easily that $f$ is measurable, therefore you only need complain about if $|f|^p$ is integrable and Fatou's lemma show it nicely. If you are unsure of your solution you can ever check the proof of Fatou's lemma and see why its true

Comment: @colossal - I think I see what you mean, but now that you say that I have an idea on how to conclude: since $||f||_{p} \leq 1$ does this mean $f \in L^{p}(E)$ since $||f||_{p}$ is finite?

Comment: That is the definition of the space, so yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest:

Since

$$\begin{align}
\|f\|_p &= \left(\int_{E} |f|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_{E} |f_n|^p\right)^{\frac1p}\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p\\
&\leqslant 1
\end{align}$$

we have that $||f||_{p} \leq 1$ and hence finite and therefore $f\in L^{p}(E).$